# Start systemd service before stopping it on restart

Tags: systemd, process

By default, when systemd is asked to restart service, it stops first process and then starts second, so timeline looks like this:

```
PROCESS A
--------[stopped]
                    [started]--------
                    PROCESS B
```

I can't afford any downtime of service, but two services started together is OK, so I want timeline look like this:

```
PROCESS A
------------------[stopped]
        [started]------------------
        PROCESS B
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=) mention that '...service restart requests are implemented as stop operations followed by start operations...'. Perhaps you need a wrapper script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a work-around: create multiple instances of the service, then start a second one before stopping the first one.

Configure your unit file, named for example: `/etc/systemd/system/mymonitor@.service` (the `@` is required):

```
[Install]
# for example
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
# for example
Description=mymonitor %i

[Service]
# for example; the %i may not be useful in your case
ExecStart=/path/to/monitor %i
```

Discover it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable mymonitor@thisone
```

... and at boot-time, you'll get your monitor started with an instance name of "thisone".

Now, when you want to restart the service, you use a script with a simple test:

```
#!/bin/sh
if systemctl is-active mymonitor@thisone > /dev/null
then
  systemctl start mymonitor@thatone &&
  systemctl stop mymonitor@thisone
else if systemctl is-active mymonitor@thatone
  systemctl start mymonitor@thisone &&
  systemctl stop mymonitor@thatone
else
  echo Houston, we have a problem
  # or perhaps you want to start, with: systemctl start mymonitor@thisone
fi
```

If you need some more overlap time between the start and stop, then build it in with something like:

```
# ...
if systemctl start mymonitor@thisone
then
  sleep 7
  systemctl stop mymonitor@thatone
fi
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is directly possible to achieve on just one node without a load balancer, firewall rules or to re-route traffic.  It is certainly outside the scope of systemd.

The reason is the service will occupy at a listening port.   To achieve zero downtime there must never be a time when clients are directed to a non-existent port or a port with a shutting-down service on.  But you can't run both `Process A` and `Process B` on the same port and IP at the same time.

To achieve zero downtime, you must start the new process on a different port to the old one and then use something like firewall rules or a load balancer to redirect traffic from the old port to the new port.  Then you must wait for old clients to disconnect.  Then (and only then) you can shut down the the old service.

The "Normal" way to achieve this is with two nodes (two servers) sitting behind a load-balencer.  In this scenario you can restart a node by temporarily re-configuring the load-balancer to point to the other node and re-configure it back again once the restart has completed.

This is well beyond the scope of systemd.  If you want to automate the process using firewalls and automatic re-configuration of the service to use a different port, you could build a complex set of scripts to achieve it and wire this in as a customised `reload` option.

Comment: The service actually will not occupate any ports or sockets because it's not really a server. It's monitoring software.

Comment: You might need to supply more details on what this service is and what the impact of overlapping / a gap in monitoring would be.

Comment: Overlapping is totally OK, gap is not OK. Service only does idempotent requests to various services.